# How to determine fire hazard of heating ethylene glycol to dissolve borax and boric acid

Tags: solutions, home-experiment, safety, applied-chemistry

I am looking to replicate instructions provided in the last paragrph of [this article](http://www.angelfire.com/nc3/davecarnell/rot.html) that requires dissolving [borax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borax) (Sodium Tetraborate decahydrate ($\ce{Na2B4O7·10H2O}$)) and [boric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boric_acid) in [ethylene glycol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylene_glycol), for reasons of practicality and cost efficiency supplied in the impure form of concentrated automotive anti-freeze.

For reasons out of scope of this question I've modified the ratio provided as follows:

- 5 kg anti-freeze
- 2.5 kg Sodium Tetraborate decahydrate
- 1 kg Boric acid

In order to dissolve the borax completely it is necessary to boil off the water of crystallisation plus any water impurities in the anti-freeze.

While I have water in the system, the temperature of the mix is expected to be stable at around 100 °C, but once the water is removed the temperature will rise to potentially dangerous levels if the heat source is not removed in time.

I would like to understand the risks of this operation. The flash point of (pure) ethylene glycol is, according to Wikipedia, at 111 °C. The autoignition temperature is listed as 410 °C and seems to be safely above the boiling point of ethylene glycol (it would boil off before it auto ignites). However this [hazard sheet](http://hazard.com/msds/mf/baker/baker/files/e5125.htm) for ethylene glycol states it 'causes ignition' at 100 °C in combination with (amongst others) Sodium Chlorite (no more details given).

Can I assume that Borax and Boric acid are 'safe' as they are not listed on the hazard sheet?

Is there an (online) reference where I can find out how Borax and Boric acid modulate the flash point and auto ignition temperature of Ethylene Glycol?

Answer (score 1):

Chlorates, perchlorates, [permanganates and other **strong oxidants** conflagrate even at room temperature with ethylene glycol](http://www.sei-ind.com/products/fire-ignition-spheres).

Boric acid and borax, however, are *not* considered strong oxidants and should *probably* be safe to dissolve below the boiling point of water. That said, I would test a small batch in a safe place, to be sure there is not a large gain in temperature on dissolving.

BTW, you might be interested in reading of the [preservation of the Swedish warship *Vasa* in *poly*ethylene glycol](https://www.submerged.co.uk/marine-vasa-peg.php), and long-term issues with acidification. N.B. [Polyethylene glycol is generally considered innocuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene_glycol), but [ethylene glycol is toxic if ingested](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/814701-overview).

Comment: I think the ultimate answer here is 'test a smal batch in a safe place'. Probably with planned 'catastrophic failure' to have an idea of a worst case scenario. Then I'll repeat this with sodium chloride added, as this is always present in marine environments. Although I think they might have a typo on that safety sheet and meant to say sodium chlorite.